# Using/not using let keyword in defining variable in Typescript class

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

I tired using let keyword to create a variable in the class. It doesn't work.
Why cant we use let keyword in typescript class?

What is the best way of creating variables in the class, is it with let or with just a variable name.

```
class Simple {

    constructor(name:string){
        console.log(name);
    }
    let name_:string = "Random Name"; // It is showing unexpected token here.
}
```

Comment: Provide code...

Comment: because in the class variable outside the functions are considered as properties, you can either declare by private or public variable

Comment: Here is the documentation. Read it. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html

Answer (score 0):

For the structure you are showing, `name_` should be a property of `Simple`:

```
class Simple {
   private name_ :string = "Random Name";
    constructor(name: string) {
        console.log(name);
    }
}
```

Based on your code, the console log will show the name that is passed into Simple though, so I'm not sure where you are going with the `name_` variable.

```
Simple s = new Simple("test"); //Will log "test"
```

I'm assuming that you are going to assign `name_` the value of the `name` parameter that is passed in, but without more details, I can only guess.